# Existence of ultrafilter and real sequence

Tags: filters, infinite-matrices

Let $(a_{n,k}: n,k \ge 1)$ be an infinite matrix of positive reals such that $\sum_{k\ge 1}a_{n,k}=1$ for all $n$.

> **Question.** Is it true that there exist a free ultrafilter $\mathscr{F}$ on $\mathbf{N}$ and a real sequence $(x_n: n\ge 1)$ such that $$\mathscr{F}\text{-}\lim_n \sum_{k\ge 1}|a_{n,k}-x_n|=0?$$

Ps. We recall that, if $(y_n: n\ge 1)$ is a real sequence and $\ell \in \mathbf{R}$, then $\mathscr{F}\text{-}\lim_n y_n=\ell$ means that $\{n \in \mathbf{N}: |y_n-\ell| < \varepsilon\} \in \mathscr{F}$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: The only one is that it is sufficient to show that the existence of a sequence $(x_n: n\ge 1)$ such that $0$ is an ordinary accumulation point of the sequence $\left(\sum_{k\ge 1}|a_{n,k}-x_n|: n\ge 1\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_{n,k}=[n=k]$, where the righthand side is an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), and let $\mathscr{U}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb Z^+$. Let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ be a real sequence; then

$$|a_{n,k}-x_n|=\begin{cases}
|1-x_n|,&\text{if }n=k\\
|x_n|,&\text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$

so

$$\sum_{k\ge 1}|a_{n,k}-x_n|=|1-x_n|+\sum_{\substack{k\ge 1\\k\ne n}}|x_k|\,.$$

Suppose that $\mathscr{U}$-$\lim\sum_{k\ge 1}|a_{n,k}-x_n|=0$. Then there is a $U\in\mathscr{U}$ such that

$$|1-x_n|+\sum_{\substack{k\ge 1\\k\ne n}}|x_k|<\frac12$$

for all $n\in U$. Let $m,n\in U$ with $m\ne n$. Then $n\in U$ implies that $|1-x_n|<\frac12$, and $m\in U$ implies that $|x_n|<\frac12$. Clearly this is impossible. Thus, the conclusion is false for the infinite identity matrix.